# C# - Pdftk - How can i make it so that whenever a pdf has an odd number of pages, a blank page is added?

Tags: c#, pdf, cmd, pdftk

I want to merge many pdf to a single one with Pdftk.

How can i make it so that whenever a pdf has an odd number of pages, a blank page is added?

I need this function for a cmd tool which i need to write in c#.

The PDF should be printed double-sided.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using MergePdf.Properties;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace System.Configuration
{
    class Program
    {
          static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "MergePDF";

        // Folder from which the PDF will be pulled
        string altDirIn = Settings.Default.AlternativeInputDir;

        // Folder in which the merged PDF will be placed
        string altDirOut = Settings.Default.AlternativeOutputDir;

        // sort the files by the first name before the "_"
        var rchg = new DirectoryInfo(altDirIn);
        var files1 = rchg.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf").OrderBy(fi => Convert.ToInt32(fi.Name.Split('_')[0]));
        var cmd1 = $"{string.Join(" ", files1.Select(fi => fi.FullName))} cat output {altDirOut}";



        var evn = new DirectoryInfo(altDirIn);
        var files2 = evn.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf").OrderBy(fi => Convert.ToInt32(fi.Name.Split('_')[0]));
        var cmd2 = $"{string.Join(" ", files2.Select(fi => fi.FullName))} cat output {altDirOut}";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdftk.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd1;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd2;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.Start();

        Console.WriteLine(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());

        Console.WriteLine("Bitte drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste, um das Programm zu beenden...");

        Console.ReadKey();

        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
}
```

When I do it this way, I have the problem that if, for example, a pdf has an odd number of pages, then on the back of the last page of the first pdf is the first page of the next pdf.

How can I proceed so that each pdf gets an even number of pages?

best regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can shell out to `pdftk`, you can shell out to `cpdf` and run:

```
cpdf -pad-multiple x in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

Where x here is the number of pages in the file, if even, or the number of pages in the file plus one, if odd.

You can obtain the page count with

```
cpdf -pages foo.pdf
```

Then the resulting files can be merged.